# but some kind of damage nevertheless

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

> These thoughts have to do with effects on others— not necessarily
>   effects on their feelings, since they may never find out about it, **but
>   some kind of damage nevertheless**

[What does it all mean, Thomas Nagel]

I don't understand the bold sentence. Is it connected with "these thoughts"?

Thank you!

Comment: The damaging effects on others. Yes they are connected to _these thoughts_.

Answer (score 1):

The damage is referring to the effects on others. The thoughts have to do with an effect, which is some kind of damage to others.

The word 'nevertheless' in this case means that it's not damage to their feelings, but some other kind of damage.